# Linq query very slow when join master detail

Tags: c#, linq

I have an MVC application and my main page is very slow displaying information. I think it may be my linq query. I checked the database and run a similar SQL without being very slow.

I moved the data from production to my development laptop for testing and the page runs very fast on my laptop for the first few minutes but if I keep using the application for more than 5 minutes the page becomes very slow even on my laptop! Other pages seem to be running fine.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Basically what I'm trying to do is to show the list of the day's assignment list and summary form the child records.

```
 public class Assignment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
    public int SortFlag { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Adjustment> Adjustments { get; set; }
}

 public class Adjustment
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int AssignmentID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UPC { get; set; }
    [Display(Name= "LicPlt")]
    public int? ExpectedLicensePlateID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    public string ExpectedProductID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ExpCDate")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? ExpectedCodeDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ExpQTY")]
    public int ExpectedQty { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "LotNumber")]
    public string ExpectedLotNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ExpCool")]
    public string ExpectedCOOL { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LicPlt")]
    public int? ActualLicensePlateID { get; set; }
    public string ActualProductID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "CDate")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? ActualCodeDate { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "QTY")]
    public int ActualQty { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LotNumber")]
    public string ActualLotNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Lenght should be 3")]
    [Display(Name = "Cool")]
    public string ActualCOOL { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    public string LocationID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ImportedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Lenght should be 2")]
    [Display(Name = "Reason")]
    public string ReasonCodeID { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string ReviewedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReviewedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ReviewNotes { get; set; }
    public bool IsCodeDated { get; set; }


    public bool IsDescriptionConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool IsCodeDateConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual Assignment Assignment { get; set; }

    public ReasonCode ReasonCode { get; set; }
    public string LocationCategory { get; set; }

}
```

Basically I'm trying to show my assignment by day  with subtotals from the adjustments

```
 public class AssignmentsController : Controller
    {
        private CycleConterContext db = new CycleConterContext();

        // GET: Assignments
        public ActionResult Index(DateTime? StartDate)
        {
            // return View(db.Assignments.ToList());

            var detailsGroup = from a in db.Adjustments
                               group a by a.AssignmentID into g
                               select new
                               {
                                   ID = g.Key,
                                   StartingLocation = g.Min(t => t.LocationID),
                                   EndingLocation = g.Max(t => t.LocationID),
                                   TotalLocations = g.Count(t => t.LocationID != null),
                                   TotalLicensePlates = g.Count(t => t.ExpectedLicensePlateID != null),
                                   TotalAdjCompleted = (g.Count(t => t.Status == "C"))
                               };
            string currUser = Utility.CleanedUser();
            int isSuper = 0;
            var supervisor = db.AppUsers.Where(a => a.ID == currUser && a.RoleType == RoleType.Supervisor).Count() == 1;


            var assignmenTotal = new AssignmentUser
                                 {
                                     IsSupervisor = supervisor,
                                      AssignmentTotals = (from a in db.Assignments
                                                         where (StartDate.HasValue) ? DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.CreatedDate) == StartDate : a.IsArchived == false
                                                         join
                                b in detailsGroup on a.ID equals b.ID
                                                         select new AssignmentTotals
                                                         {
                                                             ID = a.ID,
                                                             UserName = a.UserName,
                                                             Status = a.Status,
                                                             ImportedDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.CreatedDate),
                                                             StartingLocation = b.StartingLocation,
                                                             EndingLocation = b.EndingLocation,
                                                             TotalLocations = b.TotalLocations,
                                                             TotalLicensePlates = b.TotalLicensePlates,
                                                             TotalAdjCompleted = b.TotalAdjCompleted,
                                                             IsSameUser = (currUser == a.UserName ? true : false),
                                                             IsArchived = a.IsArchived

                                                         }).ToList()
            };



            ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"];
            return View(assignmenTotal);

        }
  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're saying the page becomes very slow, but have you profiled specifically which part is slow?

Comment: I'd imagine this is a SQL issue. Run a profile on your SQL server instance and examine the actual SQL query being ran. This is basically why Linq2SQL sucks

Comment: @mason I ran the SQL profiler as suggested on my local sql server and as soon as I click on submit button, I see an 'Audit Login' entry on the profiler. On my dev machine, the RPC completd (actual query) went from 300 duration to over 8000 duration. This is while running  from Visual Studio.

Comment: @Liam I think I found the problem. The problem is in the MIN and MAX aggregate part. Not sure why is so slow or if I need to add an index on this field?

Comment: Is it doing `MIN`,`MAX` SQL calls or is it calculating this in memory? A in memory MIN/MAX is a `O(n)` operation as it needs to iterate the entire result set. If you changed this to a SQL MIN it **could** (with an index) be a `O(log n)` operation. That said The comparative big O of SQL is considerably more efficient than SQL than C# as SQL works on set theory not iterations. Tl;Dr you need to try and push this operation onto SQL and avoid doing it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the linq min and max aggregate. Not sure why still but may be the amount of data?

Anyway I modified the query and is running very fast. Changed from min/max to a subquery

```
var assignmenTotal = new AssignmentUser
 {
     IsSupervisor = supervisor,
      AssignmentTotals = (from a in db.Assignments
     where (StartDate.HasValue) ? DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.CreatedDate) == StartDate : a.IsArchived == false
     join b in db.Adjustments on a.ID equals b.AssignmentID
        group b by new {a.ID,a.UserName,a.Status,a.CreatedDate,a.IsArchived} into g
         select new AssignmentTotals
         {
             ID =  g.Key.ID,
             UserName = g.Key.UserName,
             Status = g.Key.Status,
             ImportedDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(g.Key.CreatedDate),
             StartingLocation = (db.Adjustments.Where(x=>x.AssignmentID == g.Key.ID).OrderBy(x=>x.LocationID).Select(x=>x.LocationID).FirstOrDefault()),
             EndingLocation = (db.Adjustments.Where(x => x.AssignmentID == g.Key.ID).OrderByDescending(x => x.LocationID).Select(x => x.LocationID).FirstOrDefault()),
             TotalLocations = g.Count(x => x.LocationID != null),
             TotalLicensePlates = g.Count(x => x.ExpectedLicensePlateID != null),
             TotalAdjCompleted = g.Count(x => x.Status == "C"),
             IsSameUser = (currUser == g.Key.UserName ? true : false),
             IsArchived = g.Key.IsArchived
         }).ToList()
};
```

Comment: I still think doing this in SQL using SQL would probably be an order of magnitude more efficient.